# Bring Column Contents Up

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Why are the contents of the right-column not at the top? And how do I put them there? I'm trying to show the correspondence between graphical transformations and the values of a, b, c, and d in y=af(b(x-c))+d.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\mygrid}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\node at (0,14) {\LARGE{Graph}};
\draw[gray] (-12,-12) grid (12,12); % faint grid lines
\draw[very thick] (0,-12)--(0,12); % x-axis
\draw[very thick] (-12,0)--(12,0); % y-axis
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\mytable}
{%
\LARGE Variables \& Words \par 
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|} \hline
& Vertical & Horizontal \\ \hline
$\times$& $a=$ & $b=$ \\ \hline
$+$ &$c=$ &$d=$\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{9.5cm}p{9.5cm}}
\mygrid & \mytable \\    % WHY IS \MYTABLE SO LOW IN ITS CELL?
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the baseline of the two cells are on the same horizontal line, currently the baseline of the tikz on the left is its bottom edge and the baseline of the first line of the right hand column is the baseline of Variables so they are in line.

Comment: How do I change the baseline of the right column?

Comment: easiest is to use array package and use m columns instead of p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the *bottom* of a graphic file that is laid on the base line of a row, so if you want the columns to be top-aligned, you need to use `\raisebox{-\height}`(plus some adjustment) in the first column. In other words: you don't have to bring the 2nd column up, but to bring the 1st column down.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\mygrid}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\node at (0,14) {\LARGE{Graph}};
\draw[gray] (-12,-12) grid (12,12); % faint grid lines
\draw[very thick] (0,-12)--(0,12); % x-axis
\draw[very thick] (-12,0)--(12,0); % y-axis
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\mytable}
{%
\LARGE Variables \& Words \par
\vspace{-0.3cm}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
 \hline
& Vertical & Horizontal \\ \hline
$\times$& $a=$ & $b=$ \\ \hline
$+$ &$c=$ &$d=$\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{9.5cm}p{9.5cm}}
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+3.4ex}{\mygrid} & \mytable \\ % WHY IS \MYTABLE SO LOW IN ITS CELL?
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Will take a closer look soon.

Comment: I understand that the crucial code here is `\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+3.4ex}`. What does all that mean, though? i.e. What does `\raisebox` mean and do you have to do `\height+3.4ex` or can you also just put in a number of cm?

Comment: `\raisebox` takes the contents of a TeX box and raises it (or  lowers it, for negative values). The height and depth of the box (w.r.t. the current baseline) are accessed to with `\height` and `\depth`. Here, for the `\includegraphics` box, there is no depth. So for a top alignment, we have to lower by its height (not quite, because lines also have height and depth, whence the –3.4ex). Is it clear? `\dimexpr` is an ε-tex primitive to do calculations on lengths. We could put any length unit and even mix them (e.g. 1cm +0.5em +3pt).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,array}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\mygrid}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\node at (0,14) {\LARGE{Graph}};
\draw[gray] (-12,-12) grid (12,12); % faint grid lines
\draw[very thick] (0,-12)--(0,12); % x-axis
\draw[very thick] (-12,0)--(12,0); % y-axis
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\mytable}
{%
\LARGE Variables \& Words \par 
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|} \hline
& Vertical & Horizontal \\ \hline
$\times$& $a=$ & $b=$ \\ \hline
$+$ &$c=$ &$d=$\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{m{9.5cm}m{9.5cm}}
\mygrid & \mytable \\    % WHY IS \MYTABLE SO LOW IN ITS CELL?
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to bring the right-column's contents all the way to the top?

Comment: Also, what is the `|l|` for?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything  it it's the first  column of your three column table.

Comment: Oops, I was looking at the wrong table.   Is there no way to bring the contents of right-column to the top? Or some way to change the baseline?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything yes sure you can use `p` column, then you need to put the reference point of the tikz image somewhere near the top I assume tikz has an alignment key